# Network Request POST with parameterized header

Tags: android, api, flutter

[image: Please see Postman Screen shot]

I need reference how to use header into the flutter.
I am passing below values for the header .

```
php-auth-user : test
php-aut-pw : test123
```

Here is my code for the main.dart

```
var url = "http:.../public/v1/login";
var body = json.encode({"account_id": "3","email":"saty@xyz.com","password":"admin123"});
```

this is header which i have used

```
Map headers = {
  'Content-type' : 'application/json', 
  'php-auth-user':'test'
'php-auth-pw':'test123'
};
        final response =
        http.post(url, body: body, headers: headers);
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
    print(responseJson);
```

Comment: You seem to not have posted a question.

Comment: So many people posting on stackoverflow with no questions and zero punctuation just like this sentence